# Hide environment depending on a flag

Tags: environments, conditionals

I have an environment which should only be shown, if a certain flag is set.
Currently I do

```
\ifenv
\begin{env} Text \end{env}
\fi
```

but it would be nice to include the `\ifenv` and `\fi` into the environment. Here is my naive approach, but it did not work.

```
\newif\ifenv
\envtrue
\newenvironment{env}{\ifenv}{\fi}

\begin{env} Test \end{env}
```

This compiles fine, but setting `\envfalse` instead of `\envtrue` produces an error. My guess is that `\ifenv` is evaluated immediately when read by LaTeX, and not after the environment is expanded with its content.

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: By the way if you want to learn what's going on under the hood when the error happens, I recommend the TeXbook or TeX by topic (... and also LaTeX's source2e or something-else to see how environment works internally)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for the suggestions!